# Change values in one table based on comparing values in another table against a list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I've got a DB on SQL Server 2014 that uses two tables to store data on projects, PR and ProjectCustTabFields. They share a project identifier column called WBS1 that I can use to join. Most projects have phases that are identified with WBS2 which is also in both tables. I need to update the values of a column in the second table called CustProjectGroup based on comparing values from a column called ProjectType in the first table against a list. So for example if PR.ProjectType is 98 or 99 I need to set the value of ProjectCustTabFields.CustProjectGroup to ADM.

This is what I've got so far:

```
update ProjectCustomTabFields
SET CustProjectGroup = 'ADM'
FROM PR
INNER JOIN ProjectCustomTabFields 
    ON pr.WBS1=projectcustomtabfields.wbs1
WHERE pr.ProjectType in (98,99)
```

The problem is this is looking at the first record with WBS1, assigning the Project Group based on the Project Type but then it assigns the same Project Group to all subsequent records with that same WBS1 despite the fact that they may have a different Project Type value.

So for example I might have 4 records that have the same WBS1 because they are for a single project. The record for the overarching project would have no WBS2 and the record for each Phase would have a WBS2 of 1, 2, and 3. Those phases may all have different Project Types that need to be assigned to different Project Groups.

Much thanks in advance for any assistance you can render.

Comment: Can you join both tables on project type?

Comment: To see what `UPDATE.. FROM` does you can replace `UPDATE...SET` with `SELECT *`, This will give you an idea of whats going on with the update.

Comment: Please add `CREATE TABLE` schemas and example tabular data to describe the data you have and another table with the expected result.

Comment: It wound up being a pretty simple, I had to join on a second and third record field called WBS2 and WBS3 then it worked.